# How do I convert `--dart-define` args for adb?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I want to open my Flutter project as an Android project in Android Studio (context-click on the *android* folder in the Project navigator and choose *Flutter -> Open Android module in Android Studio*), but I don't know how to pass the arguments currently being passed with `--dart-define`.

Here's an example of a key/value pair that could be passed in *Additional run args* for a Flutter *Run/Debug Configuration*:

`--dart-define=key=value`

This could then be used in my Dart code with something like:

`var value = const String.fromEnvironment("key");`

How should this `--dart-define=key=value` be written in an Android *Run/Debug Configuration* for the Android version of my Flutter project to use this arg?

Comment: tried "Program arguments" field when creating / updating run configuration?

Comment: @pskink I don't see "Program arguments" in this Android Studio dialog, but I'm willing to try if you want to point it out in an answer.